# Dynamic To email addresses in Triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cloudpage, triggered-send

I want to dynamically assign To email address in Triggered send based on data populated in DE. Can someone please let me know if it's possible and also if the approach seems reasonable keeping in mind the requirement is to conditionally send email to either address1 or address2 based on form data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies if my question is not framed clearly, I want to basically send email to address 1 or address 2 based on radio button selection on a smart capture form once submitted by user and hence I am trying to see if I can do it with this approach: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312116/how-do-i-automatically-send-an-email-every-time-a-person-fills-out-a-form-in-mar which works fine for just 1 email. Please guide me if this approach looks good. Getting started with marketing cloud, thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the conditions/logic in the form that submits the record and populate only a single email field.
See: [Marketing cloud contact with multiple email addresses.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180788/marketing-cloud-contact-with-multiple-email-addresses)

Comment: Thanks Andreas for the response, I am trying to follow the thread you shared. Here is my original question and requirement if it helps better explain my scenario: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419330/cloud-pages-internal-notification-to-different-email-addresses-based-on-form-dat

I will try to follow the responses in the thread shared by you, appreciate the help!!

Comment: @Pooja Ahh OK. I see. So the submission of the Smart Capture form starts your triggered send.
What you need to do is to do some logic when the user clicks the submit button. Salesforce suggests to use a second Cloud Page as a handler Cloud Page. See here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382930&type=1
That handler could then populate one single email field that could be used in a triggered send or transactional Jouney.
The second cloud page should be similar to https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/29/send-a-triggered-email-using-ampscript/

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for the reply, I did go through the links shared by you. I am not able to redirect to the Thank You page. I tried redirectToURL = %%==(cloudpagesURL('thank_you_page',@email,'email'))==%%

var scFormLoaded = function () {
  window.ScForm.init({"gearID":"xxx","smartCaptureFormID":123,"sourceKey":ABC123","source":"dataExtension","triggeredSend":"","confirmationMessage":"<div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n Thank you.</div>","buttonText":"Submit","formStyling":{"onSubmitShouldGotoUrl":true,"onSubmitGotoUrlType":2,"onSubmitGotoUrl":"https://thank_you_page"});
 };